# CSV file losing content when uploading to sftp server

Tags: php, phpseclib

Im making CSV files with phpseclib, getting content from DB and then im uploading them to a server using SFTP, but they are losing the content. When the file is created is everything ok. After the upload the file goes to the correct folder in the server but goes empty.

```
 public function sendDailyStocks($StocksInno, $StocksFarfetch, $myfile){

       $return = true;

       if (!$this->put($StocksFarfetch.$myfile, $this->get($StocksInno.$myfile))){

           $return = false;
       }else{

           if(!unlink($StocksInno.$myfile)){

               $return = false;
           }

       }
       return $return;
    }
```

Any ideias what can be? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i figured it out. It was working fine but then it started to send empty files idk why, but i changed this line:

```
 if (!$this->put($StocksFarfetch.$myfile, $this->get($StocksInno.$myfile)))
```

to this

```
if (!$this->put($StocksFarfetch.$myfile, $StocksInno.$myfile, SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE))
```

wich makes more sence to me, but since it was working with the other line idk what happen. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Remove unlink($StocksInno.$myfile)) then try

Comment: lol bro that makes no sence. The unlink will only be called after the file is in server. Has nothing to do with the content.